# NO Southbridge IOAPIC found

Tags: 20.04, amd-ryzen

I started my PC today and I saw the error messages regarding IOAPIC[4] not in IVRS table and few others.It gets me back to this emergency mode whenever I start ubuntu.Windows 10 in my system is working fine.

It also says `can't request region for resource [mem 0xddddd000-0xddde0fff]`.
Here is the complete image of error.[image: I need help in fixing this]

Please help me in getting rid of this error.

*Edit: Complete error message*
[image]

Comment: tell us more about your setup. is this a dual boot? can you still boot/ reach a root shell?

Comment: @j0h yes it is a dual boot.I can easily start windows 10 and yes, I can reach the root shell. It is a lenevo IdeaPad 330 laptop. My ubuntu version is 20.04. If you need any more details, please let me know !

Comment: well, this seems to be a known bug. lenovo seems to think booting in uefi mode will help, though Im not sure about that. another thread I was reading said the error vanished after a bios update. everything else says this is a non critical bug, as in it shouldnt prevent your system from booting. does this computer even have a southbridge? are you able to boot into the desktop mode?

Comment: @j0h, there was no such bug yesterday. Also I am not able to switch to the desktop mode in ubuntu.But I can start windows 10.I will try to update my bios to see if the bug is resolved or not

Comment: @j0h still not able to open. I have updated my question by adding all error messages.Can u please look into it again ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was actually the combination of 3 problems. I resolved them one by one after hours of researches and struggles.

First access the maintenance mode as root user.

Then run

1. `nano /etc/default/grub`
2. Replace the content of the line `GRUP_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` by `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash ivrs_ioapic[4]=00:14.0 ivrs_ioapic[5]=00:00.2 iommu=soft"`
3. Save and exit
4. In my case,there were few corrupt files in `/dev/sda9`. So I ran `fsck /dev/sda9` and gave y to all queries.
5. Next Reboot using `reboot` command

If still you are unable to boot, then disable `SECURE BOOT` in BIOS setting and reboot again.

If still you are unable to open, then enter the recovery mode and look for the error and do research for your error.

**EDIT: I posted this answer using my ubuntu OS that i troubleshot few hours ago.**

Comment: Well done, I'm glad you got it sorted out.